# How to distinguish string and RegEx string in Typescript?

Tags: regex, typescript, string

I need to distinguish an incoming value between a string and a RegExp string.

My first attempt was something like this:

```js
myMethod(value: string | RegExp): boolean {
  let pattern: RegExp;
  if (value instanceof RegExp) {
    pattern = value;
  } else {
    pattern = new RegExp(`^${value}$`);
  }
  return this.#myString.match(pattern) !== null;
}
```

The incoming values can also be something like
`0|1`, `myString`, `\d\d\d\d`, `^\w .*`, or `(0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\\d\\d`.

And with my approach these are all considered as strings and not RegExp. What am I missing here?

Comment: "*But these are all considered as strings and not RegExp. What am I missing here?*" nothing. You're missing nothing. There is just no such thing as a "RegEx string". There is no way to indetify a regex in string form because it's a textual format anyway. `"hello"` is a valid string, it's also a valid pattern `/hello/`.

Comment: Use `myMethod(/0|1/)` instead of `myMethod('0|1')`.

Answer (score -2):

this definition `myMethod(value: string | RegExp): boolean` says that `value` can be either string or an instance of RegExp class.

you can create an instance of RegExp from two different ways:

1. /<pattern>/
2. new RegExp('pattern')

notice that "^a*", '^a*' and `^${a}*` are all strings so they won't be considered a instance of RegExp just because they have some of the characteristics of it

here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4FkCmUAWcAmAFAG4CGANiJgFyIDOUATjGAOaIA%20iASpqwKIAPAA4BKRAG8AUIkTlsiYaShRMjMLV4CRAbhmIICOnHkA6cnFYkKVRCwalImOMB58hY-TFfXKmO2AOTi5u2mKS%20rJKKmpIALyIZH56sgC%20iJjkdP7SslHKquqICWCYAO6hHoQABgB6ACQSSVSp9dWiKYipUt1SaFi4BIQA5KR0w6J9GNh4RAD0tWNzk-0zQ6UVWlWj46KiQA)